# Como cancelar envio de formulario si no cumple las validaciones

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario de registro el cual tiene ciertas validaciones para los campos type "password"
necesito que cuando no cumpla alguna validación el formulario no se envie.
Esta es mi funcion javaScript con la que valido las contraseñas:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var longitud = false,
    minuscula = false,
    numero = false,
    mayuscula = false;
    $('#password').keyup(function() {
        var pswd = $(this).val();
        if (pswd.length < 8) {
            $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            longitud = false;
        } else {
            $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            longitud = true;
        }

        if (pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
            $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            mayuscula = true;
        } else {
            $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            mayuscula = false;
        }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

para cancelar debes evitar el comportamiento por defecto con

```
event.preventDefault();
```

y para enviar debes utilizar el metodo submit()

## ejemplo:

```js
let form = document.querySelector("form");
let logitud = false
let mayuscula = false;
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
 // cancela el comportamiento por defecto
 event.preventDefault();
 
 // resto del codigo
 
 if(longitud && mayuscula){
   // enviamos si pasa los requisitos!
   form.submit()
 }
 
})
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Eso no es lo qué está buscando. Creo que se refiere que si al presionar las teclas los campos no cumplen las condiciones no deje enviar el formulario o no lo permita. Creo que se puede solucionar haciendo estableciendo como primera cosa el botón de submit en false. Luego, un if, y preguntar si los input tienen la clase "valid", en ese caso, al input de tipo submit le aplicamos el disabled: false

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, y es qué al no cumplirse los requerimientos mantener el botón de envío como `disabled`, te lo muestro en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(evt) {
    document.getElementById("mostrar").disabled = true;
    var longitud = false,
    minuscula = false,
    numero = false,
    mayuscula = false;
    $('#password').keyup(function() {
        var pswd = $(this).val();
        if (pswd.length < 8) {
            $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            longitud = false;
        } else {
            $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            longitud = true;
        }

        if (pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
            $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            mayuscula = true;
        } else {
            $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            mayuscula = false;
        }

        if(longitud && mayuscula){
            document.getElementById("mostrar").disabled = false;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("mostrar").disabled = true;
        }
        
  })
});
```

```css
 .valid{
     color: green;
  }
  .invalid{
      color: red;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <p id="length" type="text">largo</p>
    <p id="capital" type="text">capital</p>
    <input id="password" type="text">
    <input id="mostrar" type="button" value="Mostrar">
</body>
</html>
```

Lo primero que hacemos es establecer el input a enviar en disabled (en mi caso le asigné el id mostrar ya que no incluyes código html, eso debes sustituirlo por el id de tu botón submit). Luego, en las últimas líneas pregunto si la variable longitud y si solo si es true conjunto con mayúscula, en ese caso, le saca el disabled al botón. El else, hace que cuando cumpla, pero por ejemplo, borro todo el input, vuelva a ponerle disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Tan sencillo como hacer un `return false`. Te recomiendo crear una variable del tipo `boolean` y darle `true` al principio de la función, luego en caso de que no se cumpla en distintos sitios, le pones que es ´false´ y al final del todo devuelves esta variable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var longitud = false,
    minuscula = false,
    numero = false,
    mayuscula = false;
    var todoOk = true;
    $('#password').keyup(function() {
        var pswd = $(this).val();
       if (pswd.length < 8) {
            $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            longitud = false;
            todoOk = false;
        } else {
            $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            longitud = true;
        }

        if (pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
           $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            mayuscula = true;
        } else {
            $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            mayuscula = false;
            todoOk = false;
        }
        return todoOk;
      })
    });
```

De esta manera, en caso de que `todoOk` sea **falso** no enviará el formulario